# Declaring a string from a character has an unexpected result. Why is this so?

Tags: c#

Half a day looking for this bug. Why is there an unexpected result in the third case?

```
        // case 1
        string value1 = "a" + "a" + "A";  
        byte[] asciiBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value1); // expected: 97 - 97 - 65
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", asciiBytes1));   //   result: 97 - 97 - 65

        // case 2
        string value21 = 'a' + "A"; 
        byte[] asciiBytes21 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value21); // expected: 97 - 65
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", asciiBytes21));    //   result: 97 - 65 

        // case 3
        string value22 = 'a' + 'a' + "A"; 
        byte[] asciiBytes22 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value22); // expected: 97 - 97 - 65
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", asciiBytes22));    //   result: 49 - 57 - 52 - 65
```

Comment: Because it does `((string)((int)'a' + (int)'a') + "A"` and you get a string that is "194A" because 97+97 is 194.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing chars and strings.
This:
'a' + 'a'
results in the integer addition of the ascii char values.

Answer (score 3):

It's the order of operations, In all of the other examples you add a char to a string.  However in the third example you add a char to a char, which acts as a byte and does integer multiplication.

And then it integer is added to the string "A"

so 'a' + 'a' = 194
and 194 + "A" = 197A

and thats the results you are seeing

Comment: It's 194 though :)

Comment: Tnx! Adam answered faster by 3 seconds :)